# Prefetching model with GenericForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-queryset, django-generic-relations

I have a data structure in which a `Document` has many `Blocks` which have exactly one `Paragraph` or `Header`. A simplified implementation:

```py
class Document(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField()

class Block(models.Model):
  document = models.ForeignKey(to=Document)
  content_block_type = models.ForeignKey(to=ContentType)
  content_block_id = models.CharField()
  content_block = GenericForeignKey(
    ct_field="content_block_type",
    fk_field="content_block_id",
  )

class Paragraph(models.Model):
  text = models.TextField()

class Header(models.Model):
  text = models.TextField()
  level = models.SmallPositiveIntegerField()
```

(Note that there is an actual need for having `Paragraph` and `Header` in separate models unlike in the implementation above.)

I use `jinja2` to template a Latex file for the document. Templating is slow though as jinja performs a new database query for every Block and Paragraph or Header.

```py
template = get_template(template_name="latex_templates/document.tex", using="tex")
return template.render(context={'script': self.script})
```

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\begin{document}
  {% for block in chapter.block_set.all() %}
    {% if block.content_block_type.name == 'header' %}
      \section{ {{- block.content_block.latex_text -}} }
    {% elif block.content_block_type.name == 'paragraph' %}
      {{ block.content_block.latex_text }}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
\end{document}
```

(`content_block.latex_text()` is a function that converts a HTML string to a Latex string)

Hence I would like to prefetch `script.blocks` and `blocks.content_block`. I understand that there are two methods for prefetching in Django:

1. [`select_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) performs a `JOIN` query but only works on `ForeignKeys`. It would work for `script.blocks` but not for `blocks.content_block`.
2. [`prefetch_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) works with GenericForeignKeys as well, but if I understand the docs correctly, it can only fetch one `ContentType` at a time while I have two.

Is there any way to perform the necessary prefetching here? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think [`Reverse generic relations`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations) might help. You can define these in `Paragraph` and `Header`, and add separate prefetch for both

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I do see how Reverse generic relations could help, but how would multiple prefetches even look as a query?

Comment: If possible can you also share how you render `script`?

Comment: Thank you for not giving up on this. I added the template above.

Comment: how would multiple prefetches even look as a query? - Prefetch is done in the Python, not via JOIN. So it will fire multiple queries, one for main model and then one for the model being prefetched

Comment: This is tricky because of the constraint on having homogenous results when prefetching `content_block` :(

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I did not notice that document is an FK, and reverse FK can not be joined with `select_related`.

First of all, I would suggest to add `related_name="blocks"` anyway.

When you prefetch, you can pass the queryset. But you should not pass filters by `doc_id`, Django's ORM adds it automatically.

And if you pass the queryset, you can also add select/prefetch related call there.

```python
blocks_qs = Block.objects.all().prefetch_related('content_block')
doc_prefetched = Document.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('blocks', queryset=blocks_qs)
  ).get(uuid=doc_uuid)
```

But if you don't need extra filters or annotation, the simpler syntax would probably work for you

```py
document = (
 Document.objects
  .prefecth_related('blocks', 'blocks__content_block')
  .get(uuid=doc_uuid)
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't think this works as `blocks` is not an attribute on `Document` but the other way around. I guess that's why the query complains `Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'blocks'.` I tried fixing this with a `Block.document = models.ForeignKey(to=Document, related_name="blocks")` but to no avail. There is no view as I pass the templated string to a Latex engine.

Comment: Thinking from your answer, this works though: `doc_prefetched = Document.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('blocks', queryset=Block.objects.filter(document_id=doc.uuid))).get(uuid=doc.uuid)`. Question is how to prefetch the content_blocks…

Comment: @nehalem I updated the answer with prefetch_related usage.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an elegant solution but you can try using [`reverse generic relations`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations):

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation


class Paragraph(models.Model):
  text = models.TextField()
  blocks = GenericRelation(Block, related_query_name='paragraph')

class Header(models.Model):
  text = models.TextField()
  level = models.SmallPositiveIntegerField()
  blocks = GenericRelation(Block, related_query_name='header')
```

and prefetch on that:

```
Document.objects.prefetch_related('block_set__header', 'block_set__paragraph')
```

then change the template rendering to something like (not tested, will try to test later):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\begin{document}
  {% for block in chapter.block_set.all %}
    {% if block.header %}
      \section{ {{- block.header.0.latex_text -}} }
    {% elif block.paragraph %}
      {{ block.paragraph.0.latex_text }}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
\end{document}
```